# ol tag is overriding h1 & p & img tags

Tags: html, web

```html
   

 <img src="pictorial-01.PNG" class="logo left"><br>
      <hr>
     <div class="why us">
     <h1 style="text-align: left; font-size: 50px;">Why us</h1>
      
      <ol>
       <h3>Multi-lingual, scalable talent pool</h3>
       <h3>Positive Attitude</h3>
       <h3>Agents with little to no accent</h3>
       <h3>Cost efficient quality operations</h3>
       <h3>Government support for the industry</h3>

      </ol>
      <img src="Egypt-Flag-Map-MEast-Africa.PNG" class="about pic">
      <img src="Cairo.jpg" class="about pic">


     </div>
    <h1>How we do it</h1>
    <p>We are keen to build and maintain a long term<br>
    foundation of high performance throughout our<br>
    organization by diligently adopting and reinforcing<br>
    world-class standards</p>
      <img src="pictorial-01.PNG" class="logo left"><br>
      <hr>
```

With the picture you'll get what im saying im sorry im new to this
Im trying to put the logo under it so it makes like a break point to the site
then add the

but all of it overrides

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhaxb.png)

Comment: Could you include an image of what your desired outcome is please?

Comment: @TheCodesee why us tab https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhN9AqF5zSjqngvLGQ3goJLYK1xy and the how we do it https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhN9AqF5zSjqngyqo6uJTvJ5jPv4

Answer (score 0):

**OL**
The OL tag is an ordered list, however the text you are presenting has no order bullet points because you are using header tags H3.

It seems the code first of all should be set to UL for unodered lists
and use LI tags for your items within the list and use CSS to style the bullet points in a way that mimic the appearance of a H3 header

Set the list-style to none as shown beneath

I am still confused by what you mean over-riding Paragraph (P) and Image (Img) tags even after seeng your screenshot

```css
#unoderedlist li{list-style: none; font-size: 2em}
```

```html
<img src="pictorial-01.PNG" class="logo left"><br>
<hr>
<div class="why us">
 <h1 style="text-align: left; font-size: 50px;">Why us</h1>
 <ul id="unoderedlist">
    <li>Multi-lingual, scalable talent pool
    <li>Positive Attitude
  <li>Agents with little to no accent
  <li>Cost efficient quality operations
  <li>Government support for the industry
 </ul>
 <img src="Egypt-Flag-Map-MEast-Africa.PNG" class="about pic">
 <img src="Cairo.jpg" class="about pic">
</div>

<h1>How we do it</h1>
<p>
 We are keen to build and maintain a long term<br>
 foundation of high performance throughout our<br>
 organization by diligently adopting and reinforcing<br>
 world-class standards
</p>
<img src="pictorial-01.PNG" class="logo left"><br>
<hr>
```

Comment: or should i make a new html for every tab and then merge all of them into one page ?